# Auto sign out from websites on Kali linux

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux

I've tried to login to bugcrowd.com and when ever I complete my login and the home page appears I got Logged out instantly,, 
I tried with Windows 10 and it works just fine,, 
What can be the problem ?

Comment: Have you made sure javascript and cookies are enabled?

Comment: Yes javascript and Cookies are enabled still have the same problem

Comment: which browser are you trying up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with my ip it was blacklisted, after whitelisting it works just fine,, 
the time and date was set right, javascript is enabled , cookies too